# How can I prevent windows installer from asking for the original package on patch uninstall?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch, wix3.5

My original product has a custom action which does not have the "NOT Installed" condition set, so it tries to run when I uninstall a patch. I've verified that changing the base install fixes the problem, but the product has already been deployed.

Is there some way that I can modify the patch so that it can properly uninstall?

I am using the [Purely WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm) method.

So far I have tried setting OptimizeCustomActions, but it didn't seem to have an effect:

```
<OptimizeCustomActions SkipImmediate="yes" SkipDeferred="yes" SkipAssignment="yes"/>
```

I also tried adding a `CustomActionRef` to the `PatchFamily`, which seemed to make it include the custom actions binary, but the uninstall still wants the original package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verbose log will indicate why the original package is required. The most common cause is to retrieve an original file. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/12/08/source-resolution-during-patch-uninstall.aspx for suggestions.

Comment: I already know what is causing it to require the original package (I stated as much in my question). I just want to know if there is any way to author the upgraded product or patch to fix it.

Comment: Not exactly -- the original package is available but without its content. So the problem you're having isn't that the original package isn't available but that the patch isn't taken into consideration during uninstall. That's normal behavior for MSI. To patch uninstall behavior, you can try making the patch permanent. Otherwise, you might need to install a minor or major upgrade to get the updated package on the system.

Comment: I had a suspicion that it wouldn't be so simple. Thanks for the information.